# Why does my NSWindow have a toolbar? How do I make it go away?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm working on a Swift MacOS application using Xcode 10.2.1.  When I create the NSWindow it has a toolbar including a paragraph icon, color choosers, and some nonfunctional menus.  I didn't request this toolbar, don't want it, and don't remember similar behavior in prior applications (with older versions of Xcode).

Here's how the app delegate spawns the window trigged by a menu item:

```
@IBAction func inputAccessList(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
    let inputAccessListController = InputAccessListController()
    inputAccessListControllers.append(inputAccessListController)
    inputAccessListController.showWindow(self)
}
```

Here's the start of my window controller.  Not much here!

```
class InputAccessListController: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var accessListInput: NSTextView!    
    let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    override var windowNibName: NSNib.Name? {
        return NSNib.Name("InputAccessListController")
    }
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
    }
```

I've also tried setting
    window?.toolbar?.isVisible = false
after super.windowDidLoad but it had no effect.  Setting a breakpoint confirms that window?.toolbar == nil

Below is a picture of my .xib file (which lacks the toolbar).  Then a picture of the running application with the toolbar.

[image: Picture of xib file]
[image: Picture of app while running with unwanted toolbar at top]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce and it does not seem to be linked to the window properties, but to the `text views`.
The bar seems to appear when you are using a `Rich Document Text View`.
I am guessing the `Access-list` you are using are rich text views, you can use regular text views and the toolbar will disappear.
Or as noted by Darrell , in the `Text View` attributes inspector uncheck the  `inspector bar`

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I made my bottom scrollable text view "rich text" so I could have color-coded output.  But in the attributes inspector for that field had an "inspector bar" item which was checked.  Removing that check mark fixed the problem.